# How to merge two BufferGeometries in one BufferGeometry in Three.JS?

Tags: javascript, merge, three.js, buffer-geometry

How to merge two buffer geometries in one `THREE.BufferGeometry` in ThreeJS ?

```
var modelGeometry = null;

geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );

if (modelGeometry == null)
{
    modelGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);
    console.log(modelGeometry);
}

bufGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 20 , 20, 20 );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( bufGeometry, material );

modelGeometry.merge(mesh.geometry, mesh.matrix);
```

Doesn't do anything with `modelGeometry`. How merge these geometries correct?

Comment: I do not think merging of buffer geometry works correctly. Try merging regular geometries: `THREE.CylinderGeometry` and `THREE.SphereGeometry`.

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in merge functiun of BufferGeometry.

Comment: `BufferGeometry.merge()` does not currently support indexed-BufferGeometry, which is what you are using in your example. (three.js r.75)

Comment: There is way to draw those primitives without indexed-BufferGeometry?

Comment: `BufferGeometry.toNonIndexed()`. But I restate my first comment.

Comment: BufferGeometry.toNonIndexed() very interesting, thanx! Merging regular geometries crash browser page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll dance all night long. Did it!

```
sumPosArr = new Float32Array(poslen);
sumNormArr = new Float32Array(normlen);
sumUvArr = new Float32Array(uvlen);

var postotalarr = new Array();

sumPosCursor = 0;
sumNormCursor = 0;
sumUvCursor = 0;

for (a = 0; a < objects.length; a++ )
{
    var posAttArr = objects[a].geometry.getAttribute('position').array;

    for (b = 0; b < posAttArr.length; b++)
    {
        sumPosArr[b + sumPosCursor] = posAttArr[b];
    }

    sumPosCursor += posAttArr.length;


    var numAttArr = objects[a].geometry.getAttribute('normal').array;

    for (b = 0; b < numAttArr.length; b++)
    {
        sumNormArr[b + sumNormCursor] = numAttArr[b];
    }

    sumNormCursor += numAttArr.length;


    var uvAttArr = objects[a].geometry.getAttribute('uv').array;

    for (b = 0; b < uvAttArr.length; b++)
    {
        sumUvArr[b + sumUvCursor] = uvAttArr[b];
    }

    sumUvCursor += uvAttArr.length;

}

modelGeometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(sumPosArr, 3 ));
modelGeometry.addAttribute('normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute(sumNormArr, 3 ));
modelGeometry.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(sumUvArr, 2 ));
```

Comment: THREE.BufferGeometry cant merge indexed geometries.

Answer (score 3):

Strangely calling merge() on a BufferGeometry gave me some errors, but there's a workaround:

1. Merge two Geometry objects;
2. Convert to BufferGeometry;
3. Add to a Mesh

Here's what's working for me:

```
    var modelGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    cylGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );

    // if (modelGeometry == null)
    // {
    //     modelGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);
    //     console.log(modelGeometry);
    // }

    modelGeometry.merge(cylGeometry);

    sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 20 , 20, 20 );

    modelGeometry.merge(sphereGeometry);

    bufGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(modelGeometry);

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( bufGeometry, material );

    scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: It was my first try too. But with much more geometries to merge this trick don't work - browsers crashed while loading script... I need merge only BufferGeometry.

Comment: @Evgy Why do you need to merge these geometries? If it's just for having them in the same group you could add them to an Object3D, otherwise I don't know.

Comment: I need to load in GL buffer very big model, created from small primitives. With geometry objects browsers crashs with few houndreds of objects. Loading model to scene splitted on many meshes with many separate BufferGeometries show more speed and less memory usage, but i still need optimize code, one mesh merged from Geometries show good speed, but not enough... My hope is only on mesh with just one BufferGeometry at the end.

Comment: @Evgy Tricky. With merge() out of the game it comes very difficult

Comment: This approach worked excellent for me with 5000 PlaneGeometry!